# xcode drawrect - UIView bounds not reflecting rotation in simulator

Tags: xcode, rotation, drawrect, bounds

I'm using xcode 4.5.2 to learn to develop in iOS6. I have this code in my drawRect...

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGPoint midPoint;
    midPoint.x = self.bounds.origin.x + self.bounds.size.width/2;
    midPoint.y = self.bounds.origin.y + self.bounds.size.height/2;
... etc
```

For some reason when I run this in iphone simulator, the result is always

```
midpoint.x = 160
midpoint.y = 252
```

regardless of whether the simulator (iPhone retina screen) is in portrait mode or rotated to landscape. The result is thus the graphic that I draw in portrait mode is centred on the screen correctly, but offset to the left in landscape.

Can someone suggest where do I begin to look as to why this is the case?

This drawRect code came directly from an earlier app I wrote which functioned correctly in terms of determining this midpoint of the screen (a UIView spanning the whole screen). This problem arises when I imported this code (the whole class) into my currently program which is segue-ing into instances of these UIViews.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

figured it out, I think...

it appears that for unknown reasons (to me anyway), when the phone gets rotated, the view inside the phone did not get resized to fill the new vertical & horizontal dimensions. Thus the midpoint coordinates are always the same - because the view basically did not resize. In the size inspector, the view's got struts on the left & right only and no springs.

By adding both vertical & horizontal springs, the view seems to resize with rotation and the midpoint coordinate seem to change accordingly.

While I've gotten by my hurdle, I'm still unclear why I needed to add springs to the view, since the demo that I was following did not seem to require this step. Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks.